# How to close opened SnackBar on closing of screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, snackbar

I have a `BottomNavigationBar` for managing various screens. `SnackBar` is opened on one screen and when I go to another screen, the `Snackbar` stays still opened. I need to close it immediately when I switch to the another screen. I understand that `removeCurrentSnackBar()` method must be called in `dispose` method but when I tried to do this I get the error: `Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe`. It looks like `context` is already disposed.

So the question is in title.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `.removeCurrentSnackBar()` before `super.dispose()`?

Comment: Yes. I place those line of code before super.dispose. Some message also said `state is not stable in dispose method`. I used global key for Scaffold but the value of `currentState` in `dispose` method is already null.

Comment: @BambinoUA Have you found a solution for this? I am facing same issue now

Comment: @SardobekR, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is simlple:

```dart
ScaffoldMessengerState snackbar;

void dispose() {
  snackbar.removeCurrentSnackbar();
  super.dispose();
}

void didChangeDependencies(BuildContext context) {
  super.didChangeDependencies(context);
  snackbar = ScaffoldMessenger.of(context);
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  ...
  snackbar.showSnackbar(...);
  ...
}
```